# How to pass a boolean value in Laravel from a form to the Database?

Tags: forms, laravel, checkbox, boolean

I tried checkbox it passes `on` when the checkbox is clicked. Is there no way to pass a boolean value in laravel from a form in laravel ?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an [eloquent mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) like this in your model (`\App\MyModelName.php`):

```
public function setXXXAttribute($value)
{
        $this->attributes['xxx'] = ($value=='on');
}
```

where "XXX" is the tame of the database column.

The attribute xxx will be set to `true` in case the value of the checkbox is 'on'

Comment: ` public function setOpenTodayAttribute($value)
    {
            $this->attributes['open_today'] = ($value=='on')?($value=1):($value=0);
    }
`   i got it thank you .. i used Mutator just as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

When submitting the Form give the checkbox a value of `true`. This will then be passed through the form data.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" id="checkbox" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used  eloquent mutators in laravel to solve this...

```
 public function setOpenTodayAttribute($value)
    {
            $this->attributes['open_today'] = ($value=='on')?($value=1):
            ($value=0);
    }
```

if the value is on i,e checked `$value=='on' it will be set to`1`which is 
*boolean* else it will be set to 0` which is false

Answer (score 1):

Add in your form

```
{!! Form::checkbox('checkbox_name', '1'); !!}
```

When the checkbox_name is clicked, you can get value from `$request->all()` array by 'checkbox_name'.
Or

```
$checked = $request->has('checkbox_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Model's Attribute Casting?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

I needed an actual true or false to be sent, because a validation method wouldn't accept true or nothing. Here is what I did.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myBoolean" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="myBoolean" value="1">
```

this above returns 0

if you check the checkbox, and the DOM looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="myBoolean" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="myBoolean" value="1" checked>
```

Now the second named element with the same name overwrites the first, and it returns 1.

litteral true/false would work as well

I''l be honest. I don't think this is a best practice approach. It is a quite clean easy to read, simple workaround though.