# Elegant solution to create a Post when request attributes change

Tags: php, laravel, request

I am wondering how I can implement this the best way:

I have a site where a user can make a post, he has 2 checkboxes there for "resumes" and "more documents". Those two are not required, but when they are I need to save a "true" in the database in the column for this.

I thought I could implement it by writing if loops, like:

1. if both are present this code:

   `Post::create([ 'resumee' => true, 'more_docs' => true,]);`
2. If only resume is present like this:

   `Post::create(['resumee' => true, 'more_docs' => false]);`

and if only more_docs is present then the other way around.

however I figured there would be a way better approach to implement this, but I am fairly new to laravel so I cant think about any.

My first guess was to do something like this inside the `create` statement:

```
Post::create([
                'resumee' => true,
               if($request->has(more_docs)
                'more_docs' => true,
               else ....
            ]);
```

But all I got were red lines haha. So maybe someone of you more experienced guys have an idea, any help appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a boolean value in Laravel from a form to the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177675/how-to-pass-a-boolean-value-in-laravel-from-a-form-to-the-database)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a boolean value from checkbox in Laravel form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997601/passing-a-boolean-value-from-checkbox-in-laravel-form)

Comment: Well I got those 2 by dumping "laravel save checkbox" into google; they were the first items on the page. Plus your attempt isn't even valid PHP code. Not showing research effort is one of many reasons people downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Product::create([
    // ... other fields
    'resumee' => $request->filled('resumee'),
    'more_docs' => $request->filled('more_docs'),
]);
```

If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use the [filled](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present) method. I think this mthod will more appropriate for your task.

Comment: *glass shatters* - I didn't really need it till now, only for another method it would have been nice but it worked, hence I didn't really care. But that opens up so many possibilities in so much less lines of code! :D thank you! it is probably a trivial question but I didn't know how to word it short for google :D

Comment: np, thank you too, I'm trying to get optimal solutions too for anything :)

Comment: thats a great approach to coding! I also like to go over written code the day after and optimize it / tidy it up :) may I ask you if you could upvote my post? then I have enough reputation to comment, since now I can only post answers :/ if not no worries, was just wondering. Have a great day!

Comment: done ) have a great day too